# Jaws does not read the anchor tag text change when clicking on enter in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, accessibility, jaws-screen-reader

I have an anchor tag in my code like this.

`<a ng-href="#here" id="hideassignment" role="link"  ng-click="hideAssignments()" class="caption-link" >Hide assignments </a>`
when user clicks on link, it hides the content and text change to "Show assignments" (by hideAssignments method).
what hideAssignments method do is,

`$('#hideassignment').focus();
 $("#hideassignment").html("Show all assignments");
 $("#hideassignment").attr('role', 'link');`

In chorme and firefox, changed text is reading by the Jaws screen reader.But in Internet Explorer, it reads the text only when focus come to the link first time via tab key. Doesn't read the text change with enter key press. 
Please help me to solve this issue.
I am using Jaws 18.0 and IE 11.

Comment: Anyone doesn't have an idea?

Comment: Have you tried adding a `href` or `tabindex` attribute? By the way, a `link` role on a link should be redundant.